# Exporting PowerBI .pbx reports to a private repository without a Pro account?

Tags: c#, powerbi, report

My client asked me to produce some PowerBI reports using the PowerBI Desktop app, but these reports need to be visible to a large range of users and as i understand, to access the reports exported to the Azure server, you would need to purchase a Pro license for each user.
Is there any way of exporting the reports to a private repository of my creation? What would be the best solution? I could also produce my own webapp in either C# or Java, but i'm questioning the legality of it and if there is a better solution that doesn't involve creating a custom app and that works within the PowerBI license.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is absolutely legal and supported to write your own app and embed reports into it. See [Tutorial: Embed Power BI content into an application for your customers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embed-sample-for-customers) for example.

If you want to avoid writing custom apps, you have these options:

- Publish these reports in one place and share the account credentials with everybody (obviously not a good solution).
- Publish these reports in one place and share them public using [Publish to web](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-publish-to-web) (note this will make the data public, visible to anyone who knows the link, and also has some [limitations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-publish-to-web#limitations) regarding data export, RLS and some others - still not recommended).
- Don't use Power BI Service, but place .pbix files on a file share visible to all client users (it may be also in [OneDrive](https://onedrive.live.com/about/en-us/business/), [Azure Files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-how-to-create-file-share), etc.)
- Export the reports to [PDF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/consumer/end-user-pdf) or [PowerPoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/consumer/end-user-powerpoint) and share these files with the end-users.
- Buy [Power BI Premium](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi-premium/). If reports are published to a workspace assigned to Power BI Premium P SKU dedicated capacity, viewers doesn't need Power BI Pro license, but can consume the reports with Power BI Free license.